# How to show python output on webpage using html

Tags: python, html, web

Helo,
I am a newbie ;
I know I can use `<p>`
This is for showing a text on the webpage using `HTML` but
I have a file name `my.py`
And it have a code

```
print("Helo");
```

So now I have to show this helo on the screen so how can I do that

Comment: Can you clarify your desired output please? You can setup a simple web server to host a web page that contains the HTML "Hello" is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/) Tutorial to create a basic web server that will display any HTML you want if that's what you're looking for.